# Change the attach-pictures icon to something more appropriate?

Tags: feature-request, status-review, user-interface, images, uploader

We spend a lot of time explaining to newbies that the "attach photo" button is the mountain-landscape icon.

Aren't we overdue to replace that icon with something more self-evident, like a camera? Very few, if any, pictures posted to SE will ever be landscapes, whether or not they are in landscape aspect ratio.

Comment: Many people will be familiar with the landscape icon from other programs. For example MS office uses it as well https://erinwrightwriting.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/Word-365-Insert-Picture-From-Menu.jpg On the other hand a camera icon might make users think it would actually create a screenshot instead of using an already existing image.

Comment: Many people appear to be unfamiliar with it, in my experience. The question is, can we find something that will communicate clearly to everyone, even if it is not anyone's first choice? I'm not wedded to camera, but /\/\ certainly doesn't say "insert picture" to me.

Comment: Or maybe put folks through a more active tour of the editor the first time they post a question.

Comment: Related: [Where did the Mountain + Sun Image Iconography Originate?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/141160/where-did-the-mountain-sun-image-iconography-originate)

Comment: I'm sure in a few years the camera would be something like the floppy disk... a legacy of the past :D

Comment: On Stack Overflow, the issue is that that button is much too visible/discoverable and "newbies" abuse it all the time.

Comment: The landscape icon seems pretty ubiquitous to me. Reddit and Facebook use it so it seems "standard". And a camera icon doesn't make sense for some sites on the network because a lot of the images people will upload will be screenshots, not photos from a camera. Are you sure they wouldn't understand if you just said "image icon" instead of "mountain-landscape icon"?

Answer (score 15):

This made me curious, so I did Google search for "image upload icon".

Those are the image results:

[image: results of Image Search by Google for image upload icon]

This pretty much speaks for itself. All top results are what SE are using, then there are many with the upload arrow as icon, and only very few use camera icon as you suggested.

Comment: Would love to know why that came to be the norm; where did the "landscape" picture icon come from?

Comment: @zcoop98 good question! Might be worth asking somewhere. ;-)

Comment: Not quite. "All the top results" have either a + or an upload arrow in addition to the landscape shape. Indeed, almost all the results do, no matter what shape they use. Maybe the take-away here is that we need to add that hint.

Comment: @zcoop98 may be a question for https://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @zcoop98, Sam Carter [posted a link under the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393199/change-the-attach-pictures-icon-to-something-more-appropriate#comment1315020_393199)

Comment: The Image button isn't necessarily for *uploading* images.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace so what is it for?

Comment: You can upload images, or you can just paste links to already uploaded images.

Comment: @ElementsinSpace not really. The icon discussed here is only for uploading images. Even if you upload via a link, it will still upload the image to the SE imgur account. There are just few ways to upload: browse, paste, or URL. (once called "from the web", can still see it in the old image upload used in chat.)

Comment: Images that are already on imgur can be [linked to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwnxO.png) without uploading anything.